# How to get the highest non-incrementing id-value from all tables

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a database with an arbitrary amount of tables that all have an id-column which is an integer, but it's **not** auto-incrementing. Instead the integer is always set by my entity manager.

Every time my app starts I would like to ask the database "hey what's the highest id value you have in all your tables?". So that from that moment on I can auto-increment it myself in my entities.

I tried this: `SELECT MAX(id) FROM (SHOW TABLES)`, but of course that didn't work. I would like to use a query where I don't have to specify in the query which tables I have exactly, because I don't want to have to change the query every time I add a table to the mix.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: This is a bad idea imo and will cause you problems with race conditions.

Comment: And there's no way to solve that?

Comment: Well, that's part of the auto increment is used for. The ID is generated by database. Your use-case is a bit vague to comment on your specific situation. It does sound like an X-Y problem though. What are you actually trying to fix with this?

Comment: If I use an auto-incrementing id-column then my entities are only fully valid after persisting. Before that, their id-value is null which is not valid. I want my entities to be valid right after construction even if they're not persisted yet. And I don't like UUIDs so much, because they are horrible to look at (think in URLs).

Comment: So if you don't persist an entity, can you then reuse its ID?

Comment: Seems like an unusual problem, particularly if the ID is simply an unique identifier to identify unique row in the table. If someone visits a URL with some ID which has not yet been persisted, what does your application do?

Comment: You could use a single table with an auto increment column, inserting a record into that and getting the new ID which you can then use as the manually assigned ID in any other table.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a sequence giving you unique IDs whether you actually use them or not. MySQL doesn't feature this directly, but for a table with an auto-incrementing ID it does (for every new record it creates a new ID).

So you could probably create a dummy table just for the purpose to create IDs:

```
create table ids (id bigint not null auto_increment, primary key(id));
```

Add a record

```
insert into ids values();
```

and ask for the new ID

```
select last_insert_id();
```

to work with.